# Фильтрация массива по двум параметрам

Tags: javascript

```js
//Показывает список фильмов
function setList(data) {

  let showMore = document.querySelector('.more'),
    filmsList = document.querySelector('.list'),
    movieArray = [],
    moreIndex = 15;

  titlesOutput(data);

  //Вывод первых 15 фильмов
  function titlesOutput(moviesList) {
    movieArray = [];

    //Проверка на количество выводимых фильмов
    //Чтобы не было конфликтов с неизвестными индексами элементов (если фильмов меньше 15)
    if (moviesList.length < 15) {
      moviesList.forEach(object => {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = object.title;
        filmsList.appendChild(li);
      });
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = moviesList[i].title;
        filmsList.appendChild(li);
      }
    }

    //Занесение в локальный массив полученного после поиска массива из функции ниже.
    movieArray.push(...moviesList);

    //Если фильмов в категории меньше 15, то скрыть кнопку "показать еще"
    if (movieArray.length < moreIndex + 15) {
      showMore.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      showMore.style.display = 'block';
    };

  };

  showMore.addEventListener('click', function () {

    // Если невыведенных фильмов осталось меньше чем 15, то вывести оставшиеся и скрыть кнопку.
    if (movieArray.length - moreIndex < 15) {
      for (let i = moreIndex; i < movieArray.length; i++) {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = movieArray[i].title;
        filmsList.appendChild(li);

        showMore.style.display = 'none';
        //Возвращение индекса в исходное состояние для следующих вызовов.
        moreIndex = 15;
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = moreIndex; i < moreIndex + 15; i++) {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = movieArray[i].title;
        filmsList.appendChild(li);
      }
      //Прибавление к индексу чтобы выводить следующие 15 фильмов из категории.
      moreIndex += 15;
    };

  });

  //Вывод следущих 15 фильмов ( не знаю как избавиться от повторения кода )
  let searchInput = document.querySelector('.search');

  //Поиск при вводе в input
  searchInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
    let term = searchInput.value;
    filmsList.innerHTML = '';
    //Возвращение индекса в исходное состояние для следующих вызовов.
    moreIndex = 15;

    search(term);
  });

  //Сама вызываемая функция поиска
  function search(term) {
    //Фильтр элементов по значению из input
    let result = data.filter(e => e.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    titlesOutput(result);
  }

  //Поиск по тэгам
  let tagList = document.querySelector('.tags'),
    selectedTags = [];

  tagList.addEventListener('click', event => {
    let target = event.target
    filmsList.innerHTML = '';

    //Добавление тэгов в массив при клике на сам тэг
    if (target.tagName == 'A') {
      if (target.classList.contains('selected')) {
        //Удаление тэга из выбранных, если он был уже выбран до этого
        selectedTags.splice(selectedTags.indexOf(target.innerHTML, 0), 1);
        target.classList.remove('selected');
      } else {
        //Добавление тэга в массив тэгов.
        selectedTags.push(target.innerHTML);
        target.classList.add('selected');
      }
    }
    filter(selectedTags);
  });

  //Сам фильтр по тэгам.
  function filter(selectedTags) {
    //Фильтр по выбранным тэгам.
    let result = data.filter(e => selectedTags.every(tag => e.tags.includes(tag)));    
    //Возвращение индекса в исходное состояние для следующих вызовов.
    moreIndex = 15;

    titlesOutput(result);
  }
}
```

Как реализовать "двойную фильтрацию" ? То есть чтобы когда изменялся input то и выбранные теги бы влияли на вывод и наоборот.

Примерный массив с которым нужно работать.

```js
let movies = [
{"title": "кино 1", tags:[{"Драма","Мистика"}]},
{"title": "кино 2", tags:[{"Драма","Sci-Fi"}]},
{"title": "кино 3", tags:[{"Sci-Fi","Роботы"}]},
{"title": "кино 4", tags:[{"Мистика","Sci-Fi"}]},
]
```

Смысл вопроса в том, как сделать чтобы на поиск в search влияли выбранные тэги. Ну то есть выбираешь ты тэг "Драма" и пишешь там букву 'и' в поле - то должны вывестись все ужастики с буквой 'и'.

То есть нужно как-то преобразовать эти два фильтра так, чтобы они влияли друг на друга. А то получается что они сортируют массив весь общий, со всеми фильмами.

```js
function search(term) {
    //Фильтр элементов по значению из input
    result = data.filter(e => e.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    //Возвращение индекса в исходное состояние для следующих вызовов.
    moreIndex = 15;
    //Вывод отфильтрованного массива по значению из input
    titlesOutput(result);
  }

function filter(selectedTags) {
    //Фильтр по выбранным тэгам.
    result = data.filter(e => selectedTags.every(tag => e.tags.includes(tag)));  
    //Возвращение индекса в исходное состояние для следующих вызовов.
    moreIndex = 15;
    //Вывод отфильтрованного массива по тэгам.
    titlesOutput(result);
  }
```

Я пробовал добавлять новые массивы. Один массив бы образовывался после search  и он бы передавался в filter (мол, чтобы он искал по массиву, который получился после этой функции), и подобное же с функцией filter. Но проблема в том, что они все когда идут на вывод в функция titlesOutput - массив либо слишком урезается из-за излишней фильтрации, либо наоборот, становится слишком большим, потому что много разных объектов попадает туда после нескольких вызовов функций.

Comment: Добавь верстку, потому что с первого взгляда вообще не понятно что тебе нужно ещё и кода целая куча.

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex в вёрстке мало смысла, так как там все элементы выводятся из .json файлов. Я постарался закомментировать код как мог. Постараюсь разжевать получше. Вообщем. Тут есть две функции для фильтрации массива. Одна filter, вторая search. Функция filter фильтрует массив по массиву тэгов, а функция search по значению которое содержит input. Смысл вопроса в том, как сделать чтобы на поиск в search влияли выбранные тэги. Ну то есть выбираешь ты тэг "ужастики" и пишешь там букву 'и' в поле - то должны вывестись все ужастики с буквой 'и'

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex просто топорно сделать такое довольно просто, но если вот попробовать убрать тэг при этом, то состояние массива и остаётся на том же "ужастики на букву и"

Comment: Почему не закинуть теги в первый фильтр и получить один список? Например: filter(e => e.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1 && selectedTags.every(tag => e.tags.includes(tag)))

Comment: честно, даже и подумать не мог что так можно. Не так долго js пользуюсь. Спасибо большое. Мне это помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Объявил term и selectedTags до вызова функций и починил фильтры. Спасибо комментатору выше!

```js
function search(term) {
    //Фильтр элементов по значению из input
    result = data.filter(e => e.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1  && selectedTags.every(tag => e.tags.includes(tag)));
    //Возвращение индекса в исходное состояние для следующих вызовов.
    moreIndex = 15;
    //Вывод отфильтрованного массива по значению из input
    titlesOutput(result);
  }

function filter(selectedTags) {
    //Фильтр по выбранным тэгам.
    result = data.filter(e => selectedTags.every(tag => e.tags.includes(tag)) && e.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1 );  
    //Возвращение индекса в исходное состояние для следующих вызовов.
    moreIndex = 15;
    //Вывод отфильтрованного массива по тэгам.
    titlesOutput(result);
  }
```